# There was an error processing your payment through PayPal

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using `PayPal Express` on online shopping store, When customer checkout with `PayPal Express`. PayPal return error message `There was an error processing your payment through PayPal`
.

Comment: somehow you need to enable verbose logging and/or dig into your server side logs to discover a more meaningful error message

Comment: @ScottStensland how to enable??